# Why do my lightbulbs keep flashing then return normal

Tags: light-fixture

My light has 2 or 4 bulbs 2 of them flash on and off 3 times then nothing else but one does it then the other why?

Comment: Have you tried swapping bulbs around? That way you could tell if it was the bulbs or the sockets? Are these filament, fluorescent, or LED lamps?

Comment: I dont know much about the bulbs i just moved into the trailer

Answer (score 1):

When they turn on do they blink and take a second to warm up?  If so they are florescent.  These bulbs often have ballasts in the fixtures that go bad after time.  If they aren't florescent and the problem continues after replacing the bulbs you could have a wiring issue.